# Override an Ant property file value

Tags: ant

I have several main targets in a script. Each of them load the same property. I need  to change the value of a specific property at run time when accessing a new target; is there anyway Guys!!

```
<target name="A">
    <property file="${env.WORKSPACE}/build/file_A.properties" />
      <!-- here i use my properties-->
<target/>

<target name="B">
    <property file="${env.WORKSPACE}/build/file_B.properties" />
      <!-- update the previous properties -->
<target/>
```

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to override a property value using `-D` system argument while invoking ant.

For example, there is a property `color` and value is set to `Black`, now you may want to change `color` property value to `White` during runtime. Just do the below:

```
ant -f <build file> -Dcolor=White
```

Comment: Thanks Rao, Actually the script is not launched from the terminal, and after some search, I find that properties are immutable, So we can't change their value at execution, and to avoid this, i find the <var> task from the Ant Contrib library. It's useful additional procedural and utility ApacheAnt Tasks.